# InvalidAccessError on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, frames, frameset

I was testing my website on http://mobiletest.me
when i got an Error:

> InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by
>   the underlying object

My website contains multiple frames and framesets.
They`re built like this

```
<frameset rows="100px,30px,*,5%">
    <frame src="topbar.php">
    <frame src="toolbar.php" name="navigation">
    <frameset cols="25%,40%,*%">
        <frame src="content.html" name="content">
        <frame src="content.html" name="content2">
        <frame src="content.html" name="content3">
    </frameset>
    <frame src="endbar.php" name="endbar">
</frameset>
```

and I have a function clear() which sets the content of some frames to default:

```
function clear() {
        parent.content.location = "content.html";
        parent.content2.location = "content.html";
        parent.content3.location = "content.html";
}
```

The Error appears on this line:

> parent.content.location = "content.html";

Edit: and every other time when i try to access a frame form another frame

> Note: pls no commands like "you should not use frames" They dont help...

Answer (score -1):

Assuming this html:

```
<frame name="content">
```

Your js code will be:

```
parent.content.src = "content.html";
```

The key is `src` attribute.

Comment: `TypeError: parent.document.content is undefined`

Comment: So your frame hasn't `name` attribute. Note my answer `<frame name="content">`

Comment: Try removing document. `parent.content.src`